# Measuring the difference between p-adic and real versions of a rational

Tags: nt.number-theory

In some recent computations in my research I've run across the following correction factor:

$$\left\lceil \frac{\frac{s}{t}-[st^{-1}]_{p^k}}{p^k} \right\rceil$$

where $s$ and $t$ are integers relatively prime to a prime $p$ and $[st^{-1}]_{p^k}$ is the smallest positive integer equivalent to $st^{-1} \mod p^k$.

It seems like this is measuring (for each $k$) the "difference" between the rational number $s/t$ thought of as a member of $\mathbb{R}$ and thought of as a member of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. (Where the answer is "they're the same" when the inside of the expression is an integer.)

Has anyone seen anything like this before?